# Page doesn't load as expected in new window

Tags: javascript, window.open

I'm having some problems with the javascript function windows.open. I have the following code:

```
  if(!empty($_POST['query'])){
    $q = $a->formatSearchQuery($_POST['query']);

  ?>

  <div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
   <?php echo $q; ?>
  </div>

  <?php 


        echo "
            <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var e = document.getElementById('dom-target'); var url = e.textContent; window.open(url); 
            </script>
        ";

?>
```

The code generates a new window with the correct url in the addressbar but the page won't load. The page is blank.

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any more code? what is `dom-target`?

Comment: @depperm, see edit. I get the corret address in the address bar but the webrowser is blank and won't load the page.

Comment: ^ then there's probably an error on the page you are opening

Comment: The same thing occurs undepending of the URl

Comment: it looks like `dom-target` has `display:none`, so nothing will be displayed, so a blank pop up is what should show up

Comment: Hi! The problem was that I didnt have "http://" in my URL.